# Fix permission fail on /* on Debian 8 (VPS)

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, mysql

Today I wanted to change the permissions of an entire folder but instead I changed my entire installation (chown -R root) so now a lot of things isn't working anymore.

For example my LEMP server isn't working, I fixed a few issues but I'm still having a mariadb "Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server..." because of the socket mysqld which is already installed at the right place... I can't reinstall it because I'm getting the same error with apt install mariadb-server so at this time all my websites are down!

I saw a solution to fix this on that website but it requires to boot on a live cd but I can't, I'm running on a VPS!

Is there any solution to get the right permissions back and make everything work again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/553848/chown-r-root-how-screwed-am-i). Except for the VPS part it is a duplicate.

The basic answers stay the same though: For most installs you will

1. Either restore everything from a backup.
2. Or reinstall the partition with the OS and reinstall all packages and configs (I hope you documented them!)
3. Or change (restore) the ownership on each and every file and folder. For that you want to look at what the permissions are, which you can do by looking in a semi-recent backup or by installing a similar setup. (followed by some scripting).

But if you really want to be safe, just restore from the backup and accept the loss of a days <sup>*</sup> work.

Having said that: you may get lucky be de- and reinstalling package, or upgrading them. But I would never trust that install again. Restore from backup (possible preceedided by a quick backup of recently added data) would be my solution.

---

<sup>*</sup>: Or however often you run your backups.